# Anyone have step by step instructions for creating a page tab app?

Tags: facebook, tabs, instructions

I am trying to create a page tab app that I can add to one of my FB pages (just trying to create a simple iframe tab here folks, don't know why this has to be such a cluster****).

I have followed the instructions but I see no way to actually add the app to the list of apps available for the page I want it displayed on.

Does anyone have good step by step instructions for this process?  Maybe I can pinpoint where I went wrong.

Comment: I'm guessing you checked http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/ , is that so?

Comment: @MarceloDiniz this should go as an answer ;-)